# STM32 - Why does HAL_ADC_Start_DMA want data buffer to be cast as (uint32_t*)?

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm using an STM32F401RBT to read two different analog voltages using the ADC. However, I'm having an issue properly understanding the `pData` argument of the `HAL_ADC_Start_DMA`. I've got the ADC configured to have a resolution of 8-bits, so I can store each value as a single byte in an array of 8-Bit integers.

Here's my very simple code for the ADC.

```
uint8_t ADC_Results [1];
HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc1, ADC_Results, 2);
```

But this gives a warning regarding the second argument of `HAL_ADC_Start_DMA`. To resolve it, I just had to cast `ADC_Results` as `uint32_t*` instead of `uint8_t*`. But I don't understand why I have to do this, since the ADC is configured to output an 8-bit integer: So, why does it want a pointer to a 32-bit integer instead?

[HAL_Documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAUex.png)

I found this in the HAL documentation;) however, it pre-casts `pData` as `uint32_t*` without explaining why.

Comment: Maybe the documentation gives a hint on why it does it this way? You can [edit] your question if you think it has relevant information.

Comment: I looked at the HAL documentation I'm not sure which documentation you're referring to? But in the HAL documentation all I could find was the description of the HAL_ADC_Start_DMA function however it was pre-defined with the second argument being (uint32_t*)pData. However, I couldn't find an explanation as to why pData is casted as (uint32_t*) in the first place.

Comment: The STM32 HAL is somewhat bloated, but anyway the point is simply that all DMA functions, specifically `HAL_DMA_Start_IT()` and `DMA_SetConfig()`, the first called from `HAL_ADC_Start_DMA()`, use an `uint32_t*` as destination address type. Why? Perhaps to outline that transfers can be up to 32bits double words? Who knows.

Comment: Ok thanks. So all DMA functions expect the destination to be of 32-bit size? I'm assuming it doesn't have to be of 32-bit size though right meaning I can still use an array of 8-bit integers to store each reading? The compiler only gives it a warning not an error.

Comment: @SwissGnome always start from the uC documentation (I know for this STM it is many k pages long) not form the magic functions documentation

Comment: because this library has this quality.

Answer (score -1):

My guess is: the output pointer must be aligned. If the function receives a pointer to `uint32_t`, the documentation doesn't have to document this requirement explicitly, because all such pointers must be aligned (ok, this is another guess I did).

I am not sure these two guesses are correct, but they seem reasonable.

Comment: Do not guess when you answer. Know it first! You **answer** the question!!. But your guess is wrong.

Comment: I agree with your guess, but @0___________ is right about the point that an answer shouldn't be a guess. Posting your answer as a comment would have been a discussion point, and maybe someone could have even found the proof for it.